# Is it possible to generate a vector polygon from a polygon on a raster image?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, vector, convert

I have a raster map which I have extracted from a government report providing flood extent return frequencies. I want to 'snatch' these flood extent polygons (i.e. convert to vector) and I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this in QGIS. Simply digitising these layers by tracing new polygons would be too time consuming and potentially result in human error.

Is there a tool or methodology someone could recommend to me which would recognise these polygons in raster format (there are clearly outlined and coloured distinctly differently to the background) so I can convert them to vector?

Any help with this is very much appreciated.

Camilla

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using the QGIS GRASS Plugin..you can use `r.to.vect` for your task..I found a demo video of this in youtube..It is an excellent demo..check [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkW4hTZ5zs8)

here is a snap of the tool

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GDALTools plugin offers direct Vectorization without having to import the data into GRASS first. You find it in Raster menu once it's installed and activated.

[image]

Comment: i tried this using a simple map..for a 50 square feet area map, it created more than 1 million polygons..it creates polygons for each pixels..maybe my usage is not correct?

Comment: Do all cells within the areas of interest have the same pixel value? How did you extract the map from the report? Which format is the raster in?